# Setcookie from array

Tags: php, cookies

I have an array cookies that i want to set on cilent browsers but setcookie doesn't seem to work.I have use cookie inspector on chrome to come to this conclusion

```
$cookies = json_encode($cookies);
var_dump($cookies);
setcookie("test", $cookies , 0 , '/' , 'anotherdomain.com');
```

var_dump result

```
string(246) "{"PHPSESSID":"6a6326e66daf90c61656c089165bf9af","__ntt":"deleted","first_visit":"1452068874","ref_code":"__default__","usertype":"Paid-User","marketing":"{\"user_cmp\":\"\",\"user_label\":\"\"}","localization":"{\"locale\":\"en\",\"db\":\"us\"}"}" cookie set
```

Edit : 
I needed to put the var_dump after the set cookie and for simplicity i removed the another domain in the set cookie

The code now works fine but its not quite what i intended.I want to set a cookie name `PHPSESSID` with value `6a6326e66daf90c61656c089165bf9af`.Similar i want to create cookies and set their value for every element in array

Comment: you are `var_dump` ing before you actually set the cookie.

Comment: @Prasanna Sundar yes

Comment: You shouldn't. Cookies are part of HTTP header and must be sent before any output. PHP doesn't send any header after first byte of output is sent.

Comment: Your cookie will only be accessible from "anotherdomain.com".

Comment: @AlexBlex you are right...i read the docs again.I have now added the var_dump after the set cookie buts isn't still not working

Comment: 1. Can you please share the updated code? 2. Is there any code above the `setcookie` function that outputs something? 3. Please notice that you'll have to run the script again in order to see the cookie

Comment: Ofir Baruch I added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create cookies and set their value for every element in array:

```
foreach($cookies as $name=>$val) {
    setcookie($name, $val , 0 , '/' , 'anotherdomain.com');
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just realised your `$cookies` is a multidimensional array. You need to `json_encode` every individual value:

```
foreach($cookies as $name=>$val) {
    setcookie($name, is_scalar($val)?$val:json_encode($val) , 0 , '/' , 'anotherdomain.com');
}
```

and `json_decode` them back when you use it:

```
$marketing = json_decode($_COOKIE['marketing']);
```

Comment: For some reasons its not working here...if i put `echo $name` after setcookie it looks empty.

Comment: Again, don't output anything before all of the headers are sent. First `echo`, `var_dump`, or any byte outside `<?php` prevents any further header to be sent.

Comment: Ah, and don't `json_encode` cookies there. `$cookies` in the answer is an array.